# How do i make two select list interact whit each other ORACLE APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am trying to create a dynamique page with two select list, the first one  for exemple will display a list of Channels and the seconde one tv shows of theses channels when i chose the values in both select list i get the right result
What i cant figure out is how to make the following thing happen : for exemple when i select the first value let say list channels=CNN i would like the seconde select list to update and show me only the TV shows that correspond to this particular channel and not all the element of this list all the time
If you have any ideas please do share
Thank you in adavance
Best regards,
M.BOUTAHAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the Cascading LOV parent Items property. Create your first list (say P1_CHANNELS). Specify the query in the SQL Query box.

```
SELECT channel_id, channel_name FROM channels;
```

Now, create your second list (say P2_SHOWS). Specify the query in the SQL Query box.

```
SELECT show_id, show_name FROM shows WHERE channel_id = :P1_CHANNELS
```

Now, select the Cascading LOV property for the P2_SHOWS list to P1_CHANNELS.

Comment: @M.Boutahar If the solution has solved your problem then please accept the answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers